# Get data from one table using one query and filter different rows into separate variables (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I understand the question might not be very clear but here is my situation. I'm using laravel 5 and i'm developing a CRM system. I have placed Marital Status and Sex/Gender into one Lookup table. Whenever i get the values from the database and pass it to the view, i have two separate queries.

```
$sexes = DB::table('Lookups')
         ->where('ValueType', '=', 'Sex')->get();`

$marstatus = DB::table('Lookups')
         ->where('ValueType', '=', 'Marital Status')->get();`

return view('clients.edit',compact('client'))
        ->with('sexes', $sexes)
        ->with('marstatus ', $marstatus );
```

This code actually works and i am able to get both the marital status and sex/gender on my view.

So, here is my question

1. Doesn't this mean that i am sending a query to the database twice which affects performance even if it is small
2. Isn't there a way to query all the values from the lookup table in one query and filter out the values on the controller. So it can be something like

   $Lookups = DB::table('Lookups')

and then filter the $Lookups variable and assign it into two different variables ($sexes and $marstatus) based on my filter criteria. i.e ($sexes is for values that have ValueType = 'Sex' ...)

3. Which one is better for performance. Sending a query twice or three times or just filtering the data on the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes it does. Just install [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see it yourself. It's a very handy tool strongly recommended.

2) Yes you can do that, laravel has nice helper functions for that type of needs:

```
$collection = collect(DB::table('Lookups')
                        ->whereIn('ValueType', ['Marital Status', 'Sex'])
                        ->get());

$marstatus = $collection->filter(function($item) {
   return $item->ValueType == 'Marital Status';
});


$sexes = $collection->filter(function($item) {
   return $item->ValueType == 'Sexes';
});
```

What this does is, it converts the result array to a [Laravel Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections) so that you can use the filter function. You can also use `array_filter` function to filter without converting the result array to a collection.

3) Databases are always one of the primary bottlenecks, the fewer the query number the better. However this should not be a general rule especially when cache is used. And for example making joins or subqueries to reduce the number of queries would be deadly mistake on some cases.

Performance is a huge subject. I'd recommend you to start with the Laravel Debugbar to compare the memory usage, number of queries etc. and investigate more on various techniques including cacheing and design patterns too. Accessing the tables directly within the controller is not a very good idea in the first place...

Comment: Exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it does mean that.  How big is your Lookups table?
2. You probably mean $lookups = DB::table('Lookups')->all(); or perhaps consider using an Eloquent model class instead, e.g. $lookups = Lookup::all();  Perhaps you may want to cache the result if the table is small?  e.g. use the Cache classes in Laravel.
3. Better for performance would be to use the cache.

Comment: Lookup table contains marital status, sex and other data which usually get populated in a select input. Im also thinking about adding a country list there. So, shouldn't be more than 500 rows.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is belong to your query Data I mean your `lookups` table data.
2. You can write the query like this in one time:

   ```
    $sexes_marital_status= DB::table('Lookups')->where('ValueType', '=', 'Sex')
                        ->orWhere('ValueType' '=', 'Marital Status' )    
                        ->get();

    return view('clients.edit',compact('client'))
                ->with('sexes_marital_status',$sexes_marital_status);
   ```

   and this is better that you send your query in one time.

`